# CanvasJs data not showing on chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, canvasjs

I am working on `CanvasJs` to show data in my chart. I have placed a `dropdown` and in it i have placed static `serial numbers`. The scenario is, whenever i select a serial number the data on the chart is displayed. For this i made a local `php` file and put it into my local `server`, made a `ajax` request and displayed data on chart.

But the issue i am facing is on first run when i select any serial number it doesn't shows me any thing on chart, but when i select any other serial number the data is displayed and then on selecting another serial number (also the serial number which i select on first run) the data is loaded perfectly and my program runs fine.

For better understanding please see the code below

```
 var dataPoints = [];
    function SrNo() {
        var e = document.getElementById("dd");
        var selectedVal = e.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
        if (selectedVal == "Select Serial Number")
        {
            toastr.warning('Please select a serial number', '', { timeOut: 2000 });

        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "mylocalhost/server/index.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Device_Serial_Number: selectedVal },
                success: function (server_data) {

                    dataPoints = server_data;
                    dataPoints.forEach(function (data) {
                        dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(data.x), y: data.y });
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
   //here i have generated my chart and passed dataPoints into it

 }
```

See below my `php` code

```
$dsn=$_REQUEST['Device_Serial_Number'];
$sql = "SELECT Device_ID, Energy_kwh, Data_Datetime, Device_Serial_Number FROM ads_device_data WHERE Data_Datetime BETWEEN '2016-12-06' and '2016-12-07' and Device_Serial_Number='$dsn'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = [];


if($result)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $serial = $row['Device_Serial_Number'];
    $x = $row['Data_Datetime'];
    $y = $row['Energy_kwh'];
    $data[] = ['x' => $x , 'y' => (float)$y];
}
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
$json = json_encode($data);
```

I don't know what is the real problem

Any help would be highly appreciated